Having trouble setting up toggle menu for mobile visitors
Studying and testing HTML, CSS and JavaScript codes required for the nav menu to turn into a toggle menu on mobile screens.
Currently having trouble due to nav menu showing page names without requiring the toggle menu button to be pressed first.


function toggleMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  menu.classList.toggle("active")
}
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#menu li {
  padding: 12px;
}

#menu li>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu li>a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%
  }
  .menu li {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .menu.active {
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
  }
}
<div class="menu-toggle" onclick="toggleMenu()">
  <span>&#9776; Menu</span>
</div>

<nav>
  <!--questo è il menù-->
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



Can you kindly have a quick look and report me what am I supposed to edit in order to make "HOME, ABOUT, CONTACTS" disappear when screen width is under 768px, so they can popup only after clicking the toggle menu symbol?
I checked w3schools turorials and everything looks fine on my code. But I must have missed something.

You're facing an issue with your specificity weight. 
Specificity:

Id > Class > tag

CSS line 6:
#menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

This sector has a specificity of 1.0.0
Within your media queries you have:
  .menu {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%
  }

which has a specificity of 0.1.0
The higher specificity of an element with an id will beat that decleration so ti will never apply. Change the classes .menu to #menu to make the specificity equal!


function toggleMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  menu.classList.toggle("active")
}
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#menu li {
  padding: 12px;
}

#menu li>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu li>a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 4000px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
  }
  #menu {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%
  }
  .menu li {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  #menu.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
<div class="menu-toggle" onclick="toggleMenu()">
  <span>&#9776; Menu</span>
</div>

<nav>
  <!--questo è il menù-->
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>




You need to change the:
.menu {
...
   }
.menu.active {
...
}

Inside: @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
to be:
   #menu{
...
}
#menu.active{
} 

(refer to id and not to class)

Changing "just" this, will make the menu items disappear on mobile, but still, when pressing over the menu toggle, they will not popup. Something else needs to be fixed in addition maybe?

Of course, I was just sure that you already have the javascript, and the problem is only in css....
I will add the function that will fix that too.

dont use /if else to add inline-style. The OP already used classList.toggle() which does this fine and is the way better method. Alternatively, even a Ternary would make this much shorter and more performant.

The CSS for id #menu overwrites styles for the class .menu.
To fix this just remove the entire #menu { … } part from the styles as everything here is already applied to the .menu class later.
Edited CSS:
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#menu li {
  padding: 12px;
}

#menu li>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu li>a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%
  }
  .menu li {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .menu.active {
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
  }
}


technically it is not "overwriting". The key word is specificity here. The selector for a class has a lower specificity so it will not even start to apply. At the same specificity, the later declared selector would overwrite the first.
